# how to remove Old cached image

Tags: php, android

I am using square picasso library to download some images from one of our servers and load it in a `ListView`. In my Android application I have a feature to change that downloaded image from app side and upload it to server.

I do know how to load the image from URL because it is well documented. What I need is to change/delete a particular cached item and replace it with my new image from Android application side.

Let me explain it further. Normally what happens is, it loads an image from the provided URL and caches. Then the second time call to that same URL, if the image is already cached, fetches it from the cache even I have set a different image from my application side.

Therefore how can I either delete that URL from cache OR set the new image for the cache of that same URL.

Comment: How will you come to know that image has changed? as @Sergej says, there should be different id need to be created for new image. Otherwise you have to disable cache in Android. But, it comes with a cost of downloading image everytime.

Comment: thanku for response. i am creating a new filed inside db and saving image path concated with current time sending via android. Hope it will work for me

Answer (score 2):

You cannot clear the clients cache, but you can change the image url.
For example:

```
<img src="image.jpg?uploadTime=1234567890" />
```

->

```
<img src="image.jpg?uploadTime=1234567891" />
```

If you will change the url, the new url is not cached, so the image will be downloaded by the client as a fresh image.

Comment: yes i tried this, if i m updating with new url its working fine. but i am updating image in mysql database n fetching the path, image inside db is replacing with the same path, also updated with new image n same path inside folder. but in android it displaying the old cached image? what can i do for this?

Comment: Add a fiied in your database, like `date_modified`, and when you fetch the path, also fetch the date_modified, and and add it to the path, like in example I showed you.

Answer (score 0):

Use  [Realm Database](https://realm.io/blog/realm-for-android/) and save with particular response id. for more understanding go with this example [Advance Getting Cached Response](https://github.com/developerashish01/android-networking-lib) .

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this `<img src="image.jpg?rand=<?=rand(0,100000)?>" />` or `<img src="image.jpg?rand=<?=md5(time())?>" />`